# How can I export into an CSV file a whole database MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a DB named **demo_db**
with the following tables:

```
user
  Id
  Name

history
  Id
  userId
  report

start_test
  Id
  userId
  score

final_test
  Id
  userId
  score
```

How can I export all the tables into a CSV file using INTO OUTFILE in MySQL? So I can have the column name and below the data, i want to be a able to add filters, if there's maybe a way to add each table to a new tab in the same file....or if I can just display all the data in a single line for each user??

**Can't I do something like: SELECT user.*, history.*, start_test.*, final_test.* INTO OUTFILE FROM user, history, start_test, final_test**

I did it with mysqldump but it doesnt present the data as I want.

I'm doing this with PHP.

Comment: you can't export all the table data in just one csv file. One table for one file. Or you can build a query and write the result in a file and separate the data with ;

Comment: Can't I do something like: SELECT user.*, history.*, start_test.*, final_test.* INTO OUTFILE FROM user, history, start_test, final_test

Comment: I don't think INTO OUTFILE will works, you can create a view and dump this view in a csv file. And you need to join your table in your SQL query

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a command to do this directly, you'll need to emulate the behavior of mysqldump and output the CSV the way you want it.

```
$FILE = fopen("output.csv", "w");
mysql_connect($server, $login, $password);
$res = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM $db");
$tables = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $tables[] = "$row[0]";
}
foreach($tables as $table) {
    $columns = array();
    $res = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        $columns[] = "$row[0]";
    }
    fwrite($FILE, implode(",", $columns); fwrite("\n");
    $resTable = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resTable, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        fwrite($FILE, implode(",", $row)); fwrite("\n");
    }
}
```

MYSQL_NUM is used to give you a numeric indexed array.

If you don't want to output to a file, but rather directly download it from a website to your computer, add the following lines to the beginning of the script:

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; name="filename.csv"');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.csv"');
```

Change the fwrites to echo or print.

Oh, and I added some newlines to the output since I'm sure you wouldn't want one big long line.

Comment: "At this point do a "SELECT * FROM $table" and process the data to the file."

Comment: And the question/comment is? Do you need the code on how to do a select query and output it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using phpmyadmin

Then Go to Export -> Click on Custom - `display all possible options`

below you will find checkbox: `Put columns names in the first row`. Check that to get column names in the first row and below you will get data.

Comment: You can't. phpMyAdmin is a web based admin tool for MySQL that is written in PHP.

Comment: Only thing you can do is if you want to use it in php as an array, then do Format as PHP array and View output as text

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW MY_VIEW
AS
SELECT user.*, history.*, start_test.*, final_test.*
FROM
user, history, start_test, final_test
WHERE user.id = history.userId
AND user.id = start.userId
AND user.id = final.userId
```

Dump the content of the view use export tools in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

This snippet taken from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html

```
SELECT a,b,a+b INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM test_table;
```