# How to convert sql file to csv file?

Tags: jsp, servlets, csv

I have an web app and I want to export my database into a comma separated values(.csv) file. Is there any easy way to learn that or do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the `Import/Export Wizard`. (Right Click database -> Tasks -> Import/Export Wizard)

Or for greater control you could use `SSIS`.

Or

```
exec sp_msforeachtable 'exec xp_cmdshell ''bcp database_name.? out c:\?.csv -S server_name -T -c -t ","'''
```

If you are using `phpmyadmin`

Then Go to Export -> Click on Custom - display all possible options

below you will find checkbox: Put columns names in the first row. Check that to get column names in the first row and below you will get data.

Refer below links :

[How can I export into an CSV file a whole database MYSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485173/how-can-i-export-into-an-csv-file-a-whole-database-mysql)

[Is there a way to covert or export an entire MySQL database to valid CSV files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389372/is-there-a-way-to-covert-or-export-an-entire-mysql-database-to-valid-csv-files)

https://gist.github.com/bxt/1215151

http://www.ullright.org/ullWiki/show/export-complete-mysql-database-as-csv

Comment: im using WAMP server, so I can access it using phpmyadmin or mysql workbench... What's that?